# php strip characteres from file name

Tags: php, regex

I have a file named products_5245_20130709_101812_2.xmlGkcW7B

I want to rename it to products_5245_20130709_101812_2.xml, remove all chars after xml.

How can this be done with preg_replace or any other method ???

Thanks in advance ?

Comment: Is the extension always `.xml` ?

Comment: Or at least, the extension of the file has the same number of characters.

Comment: A simple `substr` may be sufficient here, depending on the circumstances; or just `$name = 'products_5245_20130709_101812_2.xml'`. It's trivial for *one* case, but how may this vary? Give more details and *try* something yourself.

Comment: if(preg_match('/(.*[.xml])/','products_5245_20130709_101812_2.xmlGkcW7B',$match)){
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($match);
 echo '</pre>';
}

Comment: Why this question is receiving off topic votes by deceze, nauphal, HamZa, dragon112 ?

Comment: The reason is mentioned sken boy, read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
$filename = preg_replace('/\.xml.+$/','.xml',$filename);
```

Comment: What if the name is `foo.xml.bar.xmlakjsfb`?

Comment: @deceze Then the output will be `foo.xml` - I only go by what the OP put in the question.  Considering that the OP said _that did the trick_, I'm guessing I was right.

Comment: I'm rather guessing the OP did not consider possible edge cases... :o)

Comment: [your common sense](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers)